# How Can I Schedule custom cron in every 5 minutes.?

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, schedule

> cron_groups.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<group id="custom_crongroup">
    <schedule_generate_every>5</schedule_generate_every>
    <schedule_ahead_for>10</schedule_ahead_for>
    <schedule_lifetime>15</schedule_lifetime>
    <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
    <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
    <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
    <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
</group>
```

> crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="custom_crongroup">
        <job name="monthly_commission" instance="Rewamp\Promotion\Cron\Run" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
```

This cusotm cron is working correctly when i run the cron,

> php bin/magento cron:run

from terminal. But i need to run the cron automatically in every 5 minutes. how can i implement this?.

Answer (score 0):

If it's successfully working from terminal, then you need to set up the actual server cron job to run the command.

Have the cron command run every 1 minute. You're custom cron job however will still only run every 5 minutes because Magento knows when it should be ran.

Below is documentation from the Magento themselves instructing how to do so:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your idea.

1. Check cronjob installed in your environment

`crontab -i`

You can install cronjob in ubuntu with command

`sudo apt install cron`

2. Install magento cronjob

Go to magento workspace and run command line:

`php bin/magento cron:remove`

`php bin/magento cron:install`

3. Check Magento cron is installed in the environment

`crontab -l`

4. Open Mysql and check cron is worked

```
SELECT * FROM `cron_schedule`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Open terminal 
2. write a command crontab -e 
3. write below command

* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

> **Note :- check your php and magento 2 folder path according to your project.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Filename" method="execute" name="file_functionality">
  <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

You can use this to setup cron in every 5 min.

Comment: Cron works automatically, you don't need to run that command each time. If you are using localhost then it will not work and if you are using any server then this is issue of server for crons.